# Upgrade to GRASS 7.8 - "NameError: name '_' is not defined"

Tags: grass-gis, docker, grass-7.8

I have recently updated to GRASS 7.8 and I am now getting this error any time I try to execute a command:

```
leni@eecdd4f59c3b:/app$ grass78
Default locale not found, using UTF-8
Default locale settings are missing. GRASS running with C locale.Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/grass78", line 2206, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/grass78", line 2084, in main
    message(_("Starting GRASS GIS..."))
NameError: name '_' is not defined
```

I'm not really sure what to make of it.

This happened when I rebuilt a docker image where I install the latest version of GRASS. This is the relevant part of the Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

# system environment
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y apt-utils
RUN apt-get install -y software-properties-common vim
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/python-3.6
RUN apt-get update

RUN add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y grass

RUN apt-get install -y build-essential python3.6 python3.6-dev python3-pip python3.6-venv
RUN apt-get install -y git

# update pip
RUN python3.6 -m pip install pip --upgrade
RUN python3.6 -m pip install wheel
```

Does anyone have any ideas? I wanted to roll back to GRASS 7.6, but I am stuck on Ubuntu 18.04 now for other compatibility reasons and it seems that GRASS 7.6 does not have a release for Ubuntu 18.04.

It looks like it is looking for a function called ´_´ and not finding it, but that doesn't really tell me much

Answer (score 1):

Try to add these lines:

```
RUN echo LANG="en_US.UTF-8" > /etc/default/locale
RUN echo en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8 >> /etc/locale.gen && locale-gen
```

For some more hints, see this Dockerfile:

https://hub.docker.com/r/mundialis/grass-py3-pdal/dockerfile

*Edit 1, Nov 2019:*

A bugfix is on the way, see https://github.com/OSGeo/grass/pull/156

It has been applied today and will ship with GRASS GIS 7.8.1 and later.

*Edit 2, Nov 2019:*

GRASS GIS 7.8.1 has been released: https://trac.osgeo.org/grass/wiki/Release/7.8.1-News